# What is the difference/relationship between a 2-cocycle and a central extension for a Lie algebra?

Tags: group-theory, definition

My understanding of a 2-cocycle is the following.

1. Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group.
2. Let $(A,+)$ be an Abelian group.
3. Let $h:G\to \text{Aut}(A)$ be a homomorphism.
4. A 2-cocycle is a map $\varphi:G \times G\to A$ that satisfies
   $$
   h(g_1)(\varphi ( g_2 , g_3 ) )  + \varphi ( g_1 , g_2 \cdot g_3 ) =   \varphi ( g_1 , g_2 ) + \varphi ( g_1 \cdot g_2 , g_3 ) \quad \forall\quad  g_1,g_2,g_3\in G.
   $$

Given this, we can define an Abelian extension of the group $G$ to be the set of all elements of the form $(a , g)$ where $a\in A$ and $g\in G$ alongwith multiplication law
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(a_1,g_1) \cdot (a_2,g_2) = ( a_1 + h(g_1)(a_2) + \varphi ( g_1 , g_2 ) , g_1 \cdot g_2 ) .  
\end{split}
\end{equation}

My understanding of a central extension is the same as the group extension above, except that $h$ is now the trivial map, so that $h(g)(a) = a$ for all $g\in G$ and $a\in A$.

Is all of this correct?

EDIT: The 2-cocycle definition I basically found from Wikipedia. The definition for central extension is something I worked out myself. The only difference I managed to find between the two was that $h$ is trivial for the latter. All I want to know is whether this is the only difference or if there’s something more subtle that I am missing here. Note that this is not for any course so I have no systematic introduction to these topics. I am just gathering what I can through Google. A simple yes/no or reference to an appropriate resource would suffice.

Comment: In your title you are talking about Lie algebras while the body of your question is about abstract groups (not even Lie groups). You should edit your question to clarify what are you actually interested in (or edit the title replacing "Lie algebras" with "groyps").